# The outcome of part of Exercise 7.1.4 of one of Robinson's books.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

This is concerning part of **Exercise 7.1.4** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [this search of "similarity type"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgroup-theory%5D+similarity+type+) in the [group-theory](/questions/tagged/group-theory) tag, it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

*(This can be skipped.)*

Arguments are written on the left of functions.

A *permutation group* is, given a nonempty set $X$, a subgroup $G$ of $S_X$; its degree is the cardinality of $X$.

A permutation group $G$ on $X$ is *transitive* if, for any $x,y\in X$, there is a permutation $\pi\in G$ such that $x\pi=y$

A *similarity* from permutation groups $G$ and $H$ on sets $X$ and $Y$, respectively, is a pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ consisting of an isomorphism $\alpha:G\to H$ and a bijection $\beta:X\to Y$ such that

$$\pi\beta=\beta\pi^{\alpha}$$

for all $\pi\in G$.

A *similarity type* is an equivalence class of similarities.

### The Question:

Here is **Exercise 7.1.4**:

> List all similarity types of transitive permutation groups of degree less than or equal to five.

However, I am interested in what the answer would look like, not a full solution. The reason why, I hope, will become clear from my thoughts below.

### Thoughts:

According to [GroupNames](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/97/S5.html), $S_5$ has $156$ subgroups; I doubt I have to sieve through them all, looking for transitive groups.

But I don't know how to do this exercise without brute force.

Surely there's a more sophisticated way . . .

I don't suppose it'd be difficult to put this in GAP. I haven't had chance to over the last couple of weeks, due to other commitments.

I want to ask this question sooner rather than later. I'm starting to forget the preceding material of the book.

---

The kind of answer I'm looking for is a description of what a solution to the exercise would look like, with an emphasis on techniques beyond brute force.

---

Please help :)

Comment: I personally would list all isomorphism types of subgroups $G$ of $S_5$, then for each of these work out all $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$-classes of core-free subgroups of $G$ of index at most $5$. There aren't too many such groups, which is what makes this approach feasible. But it is still brute force.

Comment: Since the order of each transitive subgroup of the group $S_5$ is divisible by $5$, it is sufficient to consider subgroups of orders $5$, $10$, $20$, and $60$. And this is not such a big problem.

Comment: How come they're divisible by $5$, @kabenyuk?

Comment: Here's why. If $H$ is a transitive subgroup, then denote
$$
H_i=\{\sigma\in H\mid\sigma(1)=i\},\ i=1,2,3,4,5.
$$
It is easy to check that $H_1$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $H_i$ are cosets.

Comment: Please pare down the verbosity and exaggerated vertical length of your posts.  And can I ask, are you compiling a complete solution manual to this Robinson text?

Comment: Come now! I'd rather have too much context than not enough, @amWhy; besides: I think everything in the question is necessary. No, I am not compiling a solution manual - just working my way through the book.

Comment: I'll take a charitable interpretation of that comment, @amWhy. Thank you. Good luck to you too!

Comment: At the very least, give of the freshman: "please help me :)" You're not 18 years old anymore.

Comment: That's just manners, @amWhy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the group is transitive of degree $5$ it must contain a $5$-cycle, and that must generate a $5$-Sylow subgroup, call it $S$. If $S\triangleleft G$, then $G$ is (up to similarity) a subgroup of $N_{S_5}(\langle(1,2,3,4,5)\rangle)$, which is a semidirect product of $S$ with $C_4$. (There are 3 possibilities, orders 5,10, 20. Otherwise, there is more than one $5$-Sylow subgroup, which implies that the order of $G$ is at least $5\cdot 6=30$. But $S_5$ has no sugroup of index $4$ (would give homom. into $S_4$, and normal subgroup that does not exist. So then $|S|\in\{60,120\}$ with $A_5$ and $S_5$ as the only possibilities.